# How to navigate through multi-select menu

Tags: navigation, menu, multi-selection, master-details

We have to build a menu with multiple campaigns.

- When the user selects 1 campaign, details should be shown for that campaign
- When the user selects multiple campaigns, he should be able to compare them

We can up with a menu that allows the user to select 0..N campaigns, as follows:

[image]

Selecting a campaign works by just clicking on it. To unselect it, you'll have to click it again. We also considered using ctrl + click to select items, but most users won't understand that.

The problem here is that if you want to click around through the list to see details of the different campaigns, you'll have to unselect your current campaign every time, otherwise the details screen will be replaced by a compare screen.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's better to be consistent in the Master-Detail pattern and display the detailed info on selecting the item in the master panel.

You can use Add to Compare and Compare Campaigns features for the item. It will be obvious for users.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought about simply providing a separate 'compare mode'? Checkboxes seem like a way to really identify which ones you want to compare. If I wear my 'user' glasses, I'd probably want to read something about the campaign before I decide to compare it with another one; in webshops I'm used to see some sort of "compare" button, which allows me to simply add it to a list of 'comparing/competing' entries.

Another question I always like to ask myself is 'Why? Why do they want to compare?'

Answer (score 1):

The multi-select list is always uncomfortable to use - it doesn't naturally show that it is capable of multiple selection.

I would stick to single selection when clicking on the campaign names and add a checkbox to the right of each item in the list. At the top of the column of checkboxes I would add the title "Compare".

This means that the user can click around the names in the list to see the details of each item or, if they wish, select the check boxes of one or more items to compare them.